# Median of three algorithm using maximum function but without conditionals - updated

Tags: c

I was presented with this question during an interview for an engineering start-up:

> A computer is capable of performing the 4 basic mathematical operations (add, subtract, multiply, divide) and a *Max()* operation, which returns the greater of two received arguments. Write a program that receives three numbers and returns the one in the middle of the three. You must not use a conditional (*if*).

Example input and expected output:

> mid(1, 5, 2) should return the result 2.

No programming language was specified.

I devised the following program and wrote it in C (the only language I know relatively well....):

```
int x,y,z,q1,q2,q3;
printf("Type 3 numbers: \n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
q1=max(x,y);
q2=max(x,z);
q3=max(y,z);
int mid(int q1, int q2, int q3)
{
while (q2<q3)
{
while (q1<q2)
{
return q2;
}
while (q2<q1)
{
return q1;
}
while (q1<q2)
{
while (q3<q2)
{
while(q1<q3)
{
return q3;
}
return q1;
}
return q2;
}
int nummid=mid(x,y,z);
nummid
```

Comment: What's the question? Questions on Stack Overflow need to actually ask a question.

Answer (score 4):

`a + b - Max(a, b)` gives the minimum of `a` and `b` (neglecting overflow). Call this `Min(a, b)`.

Let `Max3(a, b, c)` be `Max(Max(a, b), c)`, that is, the maximum of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Let `Min3(a, b, c)` be `Min(Min(a, b), c)`.

Then the middle of `a`, `b`, and `c` is `a + b + c - Max3(a, b, c) - Min3(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming NO conditionals can be used (and MAX is is built-in operation, which means the MAX macro below doesn't count):

```
  #define MAX(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (b) : (a)) 
  #define MIN(a, b) ((a) + (b) - MAX((a), (b)))  
  
  int mid(int i, int j, int k)
        {
        int x;
        
        x = i + j + k;
        x -= MIN(MIN(i, j), k);
        x -= MAX(MAX(i, j), k);
        return x;
        }
```

Comment: Looks  a lot like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080953/2410359).

Comment: Could improve and handle `int` overflow, maybe by using wider types.

Answer (score 0):

One basic algorithm can be:

- sum-up the 3 components `a+b+c`
- subtract the maximum component
- subtract the minimum component

The maximum is `Max(a,Max(b,c))`

If we have signed arithmetic, then the opposite of the minimum is the maximum of the opposites `Max(-a,Max(-b,-c))`

Thus one way to do it is

```
a + b + c - Max(a,Max(b,c)) + Max(-a,Max(-b,-c))
```

Since `max(a+x,b+x,c+x)=max(a,b,c)+x`, this can also be written by combining first and last terms:

```
Max(b+c,Max(a+c,a+b))-Max(a,Max(b,c))
```

Of course, depending on language and datatypes, this implementation may be subject to arithmetic overflow, or catastrophic cancellation in floating point arithmetic.
An alternative is to take the minimum of the two-by-two maxima

```
Min( Max(a,b) , Max(b,c) , Max(c,a) )
```

That is:

```
-Max( -Max(a,b) , Max( -Max(b,c) , -Max(c,a) ) )
```

Unfortunately, this could still overflow for example in two-complement signed integer if two of the components are INT_MIN.
Note that it is still better than taking the maximum of minima, which would overflow if a single component is INT_MIN:

```
Max( -Max(-a,-b) , Max( -Max(-b,-c) , -Max(-c,-a) ) )
```

Generally the hardwired arithmetic units would answer INT_MIN as the opposite of INT_MIN, thus first formulation would answer the maximum instead of the median if two arguments are INT_MIN, and the second one if a single argument is INT_MIN.
Moreover, some language may raise an exception at runtime, or worse, treat the overflow as undefined behavior and the compiler might then perform some aggressive optimization under the assumption that no such UB is present.

That's the limits of those language agnostic exercizes, the genericity of the algorithms might hit the wall of language specific implementation details. More specialized knowledge is required for correctly programming.

Case of overflow could be mitigated at some cost, for example by divide and conquer:

```
UnprotectedMedian(a/2,b/2,c/2) + UnprotectedMedian(a-a/2,b-b/2,c-c/2)
```

Finally, in case of bounded two-complement signed integer arithmetic, I would write:

```
-1-Max( -1-Max(a,b) , Max( -1-Max(b,c) , -1-Max(c,a) ) )
```

I think that it's robust to overflow...